# eCSSTractor for VSCode plugin not worked with className

Tags: reactjs, plugins, jsx, visual-studio-code

eCSSTractor does not work with react jsx syntax.
doesn't translate "className" elements in css. In setting.JSON written rule -     "ecsstractor_port.attributes": "className"
[image]

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to extension folder C:/User/.vscode/extensions/diz.ecsstractor-port-0.0.3/extension.js
2. **Replace this expression**     `processedEls.filter((el) => { return typeof el.attribs.class !== 'undefined' && el.attribs.class.trim() !== ''; }).forEach(el => { var cssClasses = el.attribs.class.split(' ').filter(className => className.trim() !== ''); cssClasses.forEach(cssClass => { if (outputClasses.indexOf(cssClass) === -1) { outputClasses.push(cssClass); } }); });` **with this** `    const attribName = 'classname' // use 'class' if you need

   processedEls.filter((el) => {
   return typeof el.attribs[attribName] !== 'undefined' && el.attribs[attribName].trim() !== '';
   }).forEach(el => {
   var cssClasses = el.attribs[attribName].split(' ').filter(className => className.trim() !== '');
   cssClasses.forEach(cssClass => {
   if (outputClasses.indexOf(cssClass) === -1) {
   outputClasses.push(cssClass);
   }
   });
   });`

Answer (score 0):

Found a good solution, **CTRL+F** replace all `className` with `class` in JSX and RUN eCSStractor! =)

Then again change `class` to `className` *(you can just **CTRL+Z**)*